# How to use Pandas query() method on a MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that has the following `MultiIndex` on list, conId:

```
                 secType  symbol lastTradeDateOrContractMonth  strike right multiplier  ... includeExpired secIdType secId comboLegsDescrip comboLegs  deltaNeutralContract
list   conId                                                                            ...
a-list 917920        STK  VOLV.B                                  0.0                   ...          False                                         []                  None
       263751353     STK   SBB.B                                  0.0                   ...          False                                         []                  None
```

According to the documentation on [MultiIndex query() syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax), I should be able to query on the index as well, like so...

```py
securities = [917920]
df.query('list == "a-list" and conId == @securities')
```

But this results in `KeyError: False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the index name try not use the python or pandas exist function.(`list` is build-in function)

```
df=df.rename_axis(['l','conId']) # fix it with rename_axis
securities = [917920]
df.query('list == "a-list" and conId == @securities')
```